# Couldn't find [every table] with ID=19 in Rails

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a strange problem in rails.  Whenever I create a new record via scaffold forms for any table I always get a error saying (the table name changes but the ID is always 19):

Couldn't find AreaGroup with ID=19

or

Couldn't find Area with ID=19

It seems that when the controller calls save the object always get's the same ID which is 19.  I have removed all javascripts and associations and restarted the rails server but without any luck.  Does anybody have a clue what can be causing this?

p.s. I'm using tiny_tds agains SQL Server.

Comment: I'm sure you'll find that you've hard-coded 19 as an argument or parameter somewhere. Have you grep'd your files for the string "19"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [TinyTDS Wiki](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Using-TinyTds):

> Set “tds version” to 8.0 in your freetds.conf. If you do not do this,
>   it is very likely that all your primary key will be wrong! In most
>   case the id column will be assigned a value of 19 for every insert.

Comment: Hello.  I had already set the tds version to 8.0 in the config files.  I installed freetds again with this instructions which solved the problem:  http://kevin.colyar.net/2011/05/using-microsoft-sql-server-with-rails-on-osx-or-linux/

Comment: We just updated the TinyTDS wiki page and more important the TinyTDS README on the project page https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/ about configuring FreeTDS. This goes into the new 0.91 and TDS version 7.1.